# Jaspersoft Studio 5.5.2 removes the styles

Tags: jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio

I'm trying to add theses style to a Cherry.jrxml code:

```
<style name="parentStyle" isDefault="true" fontName="Times"
              isBold="true" fontSize="13" pdfFontName="Helvetica-Bold"/>
<style name="childStyle" fontSize="9"/>
```

They come from a manual released when Jasper was in version 3.
I also checked in the Jasper Ultimate Guide, they have not changed.

This template Cherry.jrxml contains styles generated when choosing Cherry as a template.

When I click the "Design" tab, Jasper Studio removes the new styles I just entered.

If I run the same jrxml file in a NetBeans 8 project (compiling, filling and exporting) it works fine.

***UPDATED:***

I found a solution: In Jasper Studio there is a Style section. I entered these two styles and the report compiled. Jasper has written them under the conditional style section.

Answer (score 0):

Answer by @user1318796

I found a solution: In Jaspersoft Studio there is a Style section. I entered these two styles and the report compiled. Studio has written them under the conditional style section